# Adding Thaumcraft as a dependacy - minecraft 1.12.2 modding

Tags: java, maven, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Alright. As stated above, I need to add Thaumcraft (6) as a (required) dependency for my Minecraft 1.12.2 mod. I have tried different methods of this (`compile`, `compileOnly`, `deobfCompile`), but none have helped. I've already asked around Reddit, but no luck...

EDIT 1:
People have been asking for properties.gradle, build.gradle, and the error. The error from build.gradle is simple enough. It just says that the methods do not exist. I will only upload the current versions.

[build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/H5FkUntU)

[gradle.properties](https://pastebin.com/21bKFZ9V)

EDIT 2:
Even though I now have a response, I still would like to spruce up the question a little bit. So, I was told to copy-paste the error, instead of paraphrasing it. I will upload the error for the Pastebin `build.gradle`.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
* Where: 
Build file 'F:\Modding\Minecraft\Modding_Setups\Aetherium\build.gradle' line: 40 
* What went wrong: 
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Aetherium'. 
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [thaumcraft:Thaumcraft:1.12.2:6.1.BETA26] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

Comment: So what error did you get? Please add the error message to the question.

Comment: Please post the contents of your build.gradle and gradle.properties files, as well as exactly what happened when you tried them.

Comment: Added both. thanks guys.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error instead of paraphrasing it.

Answer (score 1):

This mod does not appear to be [formally published](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) anywhere to the any standard Maven repository such as [central](https://search.maven.org/) or [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter).

It seems [this](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/thaumcraft/files) is the place for the JAR from Googling although many other places offer the JAR as well. Based on the comments on that page, it seems the mod is no longer maintained/developed and you will need to make sure you're using a compatible Minecraft version or something.

Anyways, download the Thaumcraft JAR from wherever and place it somewhere in your project. Then simply update your main Gradle build file with the following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(files("path/to/Thaumcraft.jar"))
}
```

Comment: I am a big Thaumcraft fan, so I am using 1.12.2 and stuff. Do not fear, for I have checked most compatibility.

Comment: * What went wrong: 
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Aetherium'. 
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Please make sure you are using a supported version of Gradle. As of today that is Gradle 6.3.